# 2 seconds delay in analog circuit

Tags: transistors, analog, relay, delay

I'm having trouble to design a circuit with delay.

Here's what i did:

[image]

(I just tried to play with the transistor.. i know im missing something there)
So what i want to achieve is that when i close the orange switch, the upper relay will power up 2 seconds after the lower relay.
I'm trying to do it with 1 switch, what i mean is that im physically pressing this one switch and all the rest should be automatic.
How can i manage to do this 2 seconds delay between the relays power up. (using only the components used in the picture)

I'll appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: What's analog about this circuit?

Answer (score 4):

You have an excellent example of how **not to design a timer delay relay.**

Three conditions must be met:

- A) relay coil current normal= ?? or Rc @V
- B) Ic/Ib = 10~20 **(default for all BJT saturated switches)**
- C) Delay =2 sec

  - Ic, Vcc and T tolerances and Vcc = unknown, (learn to define first)

In order to satisfy this chosen design, we can use impedance ratios.
Since all voltages are common, consider coil Rc, and worst case, Ic/Ib=10 for an efficient switch

if Rc=330 Ohms , you want your switch to be << 10% of this and with Rb=33k yours transistor and Ic/Ib=20 Rce becomes 33k/20=1.6k and unable to saturate the collector.

Meanwhile C is already huge at 500uF, so can U consider a better way such as CMOS or a 2nd stage BJT to perform both time delay and current drive?

> Always define your critical output/input specs, for at least current and impedance BEFORE you waste your time on a design.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: As I suggested on @Doodle 's post, it would be better to just use a 555 if you can.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDhJGa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Try this, R2 and C1 values may vary depending on the timings, R1 should be relatively constant, maybe change to 1k depending on your transistor. You're going to need a C1 R1, like 300uF and 100kohm, so you might want to do as the other poster suggests and use a mosfet. With this design you might need a high gain, so a darlington config is probably better.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fs1uMX.png)</sup>

Replace Q1 in the original schematic with the setup on the right. 
Ignore the V1 value

Comment: That NPN BJT doesn't have enough gain to drive a relay when its base it being driven through a 10k resistor - even worse with 100k. an N-MOSFET would probably work much better.

Comment: Sorry but T=RC is only 1 sec and threshold is 0.7V/12V or 6% (not 60%) so best case is T= 0.1sec

Comment: I get about 1.2sec using 50k and a 220u with a darlington layout on falstad circuit sim (not the most accurate, but good for quickly testing stuff)

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 also with the values i talked about in the text (100k and 300u) the time constant is 30 sec,

Comment: I feel like a downvote is a bit harsh, since my solution works and is pretty simple. 220uF is big, but not specialist or anything, and fine for breadboarding. The only issue might be the current needed by the relay, which may be too high (so i guess you could add a third darlington)

Comment: @BeB00 You and me both

Comment: @Doodle The difference between mine and yours is that mine is an acceptable design, whereas yours isnt. The fact that you deleted it suggests maybe you feel the same way. However, I'll add a bit to mine with the same info i suggested for yours.

Comment: @BeB00 Like I said, for an approximate delay timer, there's nothing wrong with my design. I deleted mine for 2 reasons, this is a homework assignment and the OP's edit "using only the components used in the picture"

Comment: @BeB00. you must enter 10 for hFE in Falstad for saturation, not the default 100.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to make such delay with a capacitor, a resistor and a transistor. When the capacitor is fully charged, enough current go through the transistor's base and toggle the switch.